# Understanding/Learning scripting language(s) from a compiled language developer perspective

Tags: javascript, c#, python, c++

I have been a C-derived language (c, c++, c#, etc..) developer for about 7 years. I have managed to avoid doing scripting language programming so far. But trying to avoid the unavoidable is doomed to be a failing course.

Now I have to teach myself a scripting language or two for work. Before I start this "pleasant" journey of learning a new programming language again, I would like to have a high-level guidance about scripting languages.

**Q1**, Why did we invent scripting languages? What is so great about scripting languages (python, javascript, etc.) that other compiled languages cannot do?

**Q2**, I need to learn both Python and JavaScript. Is there any advantages to learn them together? Will I save time by doing so? Or it does not make sense to learn two different languages at the same time.

**Q3**, As we all know, learning the syntax of a language is just the beginning. What are the pitfalls we need to watch out for when learning scripting languages with a compiled language background?

For example, c++ syntax does not tell you that if you dont pair `new` with a `delete`, you leak memory.

```
void leaking_function()
{
 //correct syntax in c++, but leaking memory every time it is called.
 void* leak = new int[10];
}
```

Comment: Scripting languages are easy/fast to write. I'm not going to write something in C if I can get it done in bash. If I need to quickly do some web scraping and parsing, I'm going to use python, not java.

Comment: I'm not a serious programmer but I have dabbled with both C++ and Python. I think just about every language I've looked at has their own advantages and disadvantages. I find Python good for cranking something out quickly though it doesn't seem as efficient as C++.

Comment: @Donkyhotay, thanks for that. I understand that the interpreter sitting between your txt file and your CPU is doing work. It does not come for free. :)

Comment: An interactive console allows you to experiment, test and write code all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1: why need scripting languages :**

**Answer :**

> Scripting languages are quick and easy .Compiled languages are much
>   more efficient - for which you pay an up front price in complexity.

you want to write something quickly and then never use it again, 'scripting' languages are what you want.

**Features of scripting language:**

- easy to learn and use
- minimum programming knowledge or experience required
- allow complex tasks to be performed in relatively few steps
- allow simple creation and editing in a variety of text editors
- allow the addition of dynamic and interactive activities to web pages
- editing and running code is fast.

**Q2: I need to learn both Python and JavaScript. Is there any advantages to learn them together?**

**Answer :**

> comparison to JavaScript, Python is much well designed, stable and
>   robust. It has better, cleaner syntax and common-sense patterns.
>
> Python is the predominant language in the world of scientific
>   simulations and data analysis.

JavaScript, on the other hand, is the **language of the web.** It's not the prettiest language out there, but you can use it to build rich applications that anyone in the world can run just by typing an address in their browser

> Node.js has proven that it can more than hold its own outside of the
>   browser as well

Anyway learn both languages is a good deal. But in my openion **take one from the above** it will be upto your choice, its complitly depends on your working area and interest.Then learn that  one in depth and work on it.

**Q3: What are the pitfalls we need to watch out for when learning scripting languages with a compiled language background?**

**Answer:**

If you know the basics of any programmig language then it is easy to learn scripting languages too.Most of the compiled language features are also included in scripting language too.

**Note:** you have to compile a C program before you can run it. But you don't have to compile a JavaScript program before you run it.keep this in your mind before you learn scripting language.

When you write scripting language always think about security hackers can easily hack our site if we did not provide a high security.